# Workaround for Cross Domain Request

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I am trying to execute the below code to open URL using javascript

```
var Urlone = document.getElementById('00N0b00'),

opening = window.open(Urlone),
            
opening.onload = function() {

var Urltwo = opening.document.getElementById('00GG')

window.open(Urltwo);}
```

This works and opens Urltwo when Urlone is from same domain as Origin URL, but Urltwo does not open when Urlone is from different domain than Origin.

I know its because or CORS standards, but I need help to get around this.

I already tried downloading chrome extensions which relaxes CORS but it did not work. I don’t want to use jquery or anyorigin.com.
Looking for a possible solution using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) is a system, consisting of transmitting HTTP headers, that determines whether browsers block frontend JavaScript code from accessing responses for cross-origin requests. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS)

You cannot inject JavaScript into a window when cross-origin resource sharing is disabled and this is by design.

Possible workarounds:

- Change CORS headers on the server of Urltwo
- <s>Fetch source of Urltwo via an HTTP request and render it in a blank iframe (applicability will vary)</s>. Edit: If the request is initiated from JavaScript, this will be subject to CORS as well.

If you have access to the server serving `Urltwo`, changing CORS settings is the best solution.
If you do not have access to the server, but you can edit the document served at `Urltwo`, you can communicate between the documents via `document.postMessage` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) or by encoding information in the URL (query string or hash).
If you have access to neither, you can use a proxy that fetches the contents at `Urltwo`, sents the correct CORS headers and sends the result back to you.